# ClassNotFoundException: dataimport.DataImportHandler

Tags: java, mysql, exception, solr, import

Hi I'm using the Solr 4 beta, and I'm not a Java programmer. And I'm configuring the [DataImportHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) withing the example folder for my MySQL DB. Problem is, when I'm starting the server with:

```
java -jar start.jar
```

My solrconfig.xml has this:

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
 <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
</lst>
</requestHandler>
```

From the other [thread](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/DataImportHandler-in-Solr-4-0-td2563053.html#a3667942) the advise was to copy apache-solr-solrj-4.0.jar to the lib/ directory, which I did. One only difference is that in the current Solr release, the filename is: apache-solr-solrj-4.0.0-BETA.jar, but I tried to copy it with different names. Also, I added to the solrconfig.xml this line so that SolrJ would be loaded:

```
<lib dir="/dist/" regex="apache-solr-solrj-*\.jar" />
```

Nevertheless, **I'm still getting the exception**:

```
SEVERE: null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: RequestHandler init failure
    at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers.initHandlersFromConfig(RequestHandlers.java:168)
.
....
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your solr conf check if you have included the DIH jar, if you haven't then you should add something like below

```
<lib dir="../../dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-.*\.jar" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the files in \contrib\dataimporthandler\lib and apache-solr-dataimporthandler-4.0.jar from dist folder to your class path.

Comment: Well I did export CLASSPATH=/home/my/projects/apache-solr-4.0.0-BETA/dist:/home/my/projects/apache-solr-4.0.0-BETA/contrib/dataimporthandler/lib/ but this didn't help.

Comment: But you havent included them in your lib settings i guess? You can also make a lib dir and copy all files into there. Add <lib dir="./lib" /> to solrconfig.xml

Answer (score 0):

I apparently did a mistake by trying to use the example folder to import data from MySQL. In this directory there's a fully working example-DIH folder, which just works.